# Probability of a boy is born to the $i^\text{th}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions

> Consider a population of $n$ couples where a boy is born to the $i^\text{th}$ couple with probability $p_i$ and $c_i$ is the expected number of children born to this couple. If we suppose that $p_i$ is constant with time for all couple and that sexes of successive children born to a particular couple are independent r.v's and no multiple births are allowed. The sex ratio is defined to be $$S= \frac{\text{expected number of boys born in the population of $n$ couples}}{\text{expected number of children horn in the population of $n$ couples}}$$

Suppose $c_i=c$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ then find $S$ I find this $S$ as :
$$S \equiv S_0= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1 {p_i}} n$$

and in the second part of the problem asks that:

> If the parents of all couples decide to have children until a boy is born and then have no further children, Then show that $$S=S_1 = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1 {p_i}} \leq S_0 $$

I´m really stuck with this problem, I tried to model the birth of the children as a geometric distribution but I think this is wrong cause the births start in $1$ and the geometric distribution starts in $0$.

How can I compute the expected value of the above events?

Could someone help me to show this inequality pls? Thank for your time and help.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Since $0<p_i≤1$, presumably, we have $\frac 1{p_i}≥1$.  Thus $\sum \frac 1{p_i}≥n$ which implies $\left( \sum \frac 1{p_i} \right)^2≥n^2$.  Is that all you wanted?

Comment: why $\sum \frac{1}{p_i} \geq n$ ?

Comment: If you add $n$ numbers each of which is at least $1$ together you get at least $n$.  Note:  your sums incorrectly start at $i=0$.  I believe you meant $i=1$.

Comment: I´m just stuck trying to prove the inequality. I tried to compute the expected value of the ratio $S$

Comment: It starts from $1$, from the book Samuel Karlin an introduction to SP.

Comment: You have written them as starting from $i=0$.

Comment: The problem starts in $1$ but the geometric distr in $0$ that what my proff told me

Comment: Just I help here How can I compute the expected value of $S$ the ratio ?

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. what is the definition of $p_0$?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, $i=1$ I edited sorry.

Comment: To get the denominator of $S_1$:  let $E_i$ be the expected number of kids born to couple $i$.  Then, considering the first child, we see that $E_i=p_i\times 1+(1-p_i)\times (E_i+1)\implies E_i=\frac 1{p_i}$.  The use linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia lists two definitions of the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), but the first one starts at $1$ and seems like the correct way to go about solving this problem. It counts the number of trials until the first success is reached, and in order to have a success you must have at least one trial. In your case "success" is family $i$ having a boy, and the probability of success is $p_i$.